# Effective way to schedule a repeating task

Tags: java, android

i want to do a background service that for example will show a toast every five minutes.
i only managed to do that with AlarmManager but its taking alot of the battery and the ram memory.is there a more effective way to schedule a repeating task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor

You can use java.util.Timer or ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor (preferred) to schedule an action to occur at regular intervals on a background thread.

Here is a sample using the latter:

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
    Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate
      (new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            // call service
         }
      }, 0, 10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```